# Covariant data types: Why return type must be same as or child of its 'parent method' return type?

Tags: java, oop, covariance, covariant, covariant-return-types

As this is not so famous concept, I will make a little intro.

> **Covariant return type** of a method is one that can be replaced by a
> "narrower" type when the method is overridden in a subclass.

So I can compile just fine this little program (as String is child of Object):

```
public class House {
    Object someMethod(){
        return null;
    }
}

class DogHouse extends House{
    @Override
    String someMethod() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The rule is easy enough to remember, but I don't understand it. My question is this:

Why can the return type in **someMethod** in **DogHouse** only be the same or child of return type in **someMethod** in class **House**? I hope the question is quite clear.

Or..(for example) why this code wouldn't compile if I had put return type in **someMethod** in class **House** `Integer` for example? (String is not a child of Integer)

What is happening 'behind the scenes' so I can understand it?

Comment: What happens when you assign an instance of `DogHouse` to `House` and try and call `someMethod`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So you want to say I have polymorphism even in return types? Never heard about that before..

Comment: @StefanJankovic A return-type could be ambiguous if it was not like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to understand this is to think of the subclass as a specific type of the parent class. This means it still needs to adhere to the behavior defined by the parent. The parent class defines a `someMethod` method that returns an `Object`. Subclasses can't break this behavior, but they can further specify it - a `DogHouse`'s `someMethod` still returns an `Object`, it just happens to be a `String`.

Comment: +1. Note that you can literally write something like `House dogHouse = new DogHouse()`, so it would completely break the type system if `dogHouse.someMethod()` returned a different type than the definition of `House` says it will.